# Best way to create a numeric pad as seen in Apples telephone app

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface

What is the best way to create a numeric pad like the one Apple uses in the telephone app?
[image]

Comment: see my updated answer... i forgot there was a couple guys that made a high res PSD file with an older style keypad you can convert over for graphics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented a KeypadView, that is customizable via a delegate.

This [github repository](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/KeyPad) has the KeypadView and a delegate-implementation.

As I am still beginner in the field of iOS development I would appreciate, if you share your thoughts with me.

Comment: "The Gist you were looking for has been deleted. Sorry about that!"

Comment: @JOM I fixed the link. But beware, that code is rough. Chech for leaks in.

Answer (score 3):

I would say just create an array of `UIButton` objects so that you can utilize `UIControlStateSelected` and the other button states by using different images for different states.

Another idea is to create something similar to that entire keypad in Photoshop, and then tile it into 12 images using http://www.mikelin.ca/blog/2010/06/iphone-splitting-image-into-tiles-for-faster-loading-with-imagemagick/

That would take some of the work out of get all the images to flow nicely together.

By the way, I just forgot about these until just a minute ago... they have some of the UI graphics from the iPhone and iPad in high res PSD file:

http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/2010/02/01/ipad-gui-psd/

and

http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/2010/08/12/iphone-4-gui-psd-retina-display/

and

http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/2010/06/14/iphone-gui-psd-v4/