# How do I build a calculator-style number input field in iOS?

Tags: iphone, uiview, ios, uitextfield

I already know how to enable the numeric keyboards and validate the field input to ensure it's numeric. What I want to know is how to set up an input view that'll let my user enter a number value from right to left, like a calculator or ATM machine.

In other words, I want the user to be able to type:

```
2 0 0 4 9
```

and have that be displayed as **$200.49**.

Then, once that's been input, I also need to get values in or out of this input view as an NSNumber or NSDecimalNumber, with correct decimal placement.

For example, I have an NSDecimalNumber equivalent to 17.50. I need to be able to pass this number into the keypad view for editing, then get back the edited value *as a number object*.

Say the user edits that value; the value they see would be

```
1 7 5 0
```

Then they hit the backspace key. The number displayed would then be

```
1 7 5
```

I need to get that number back as 1.75, not 175 or 17.5.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I wrote a [KeyPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391464/best-way-to-create-a-numeric-pad-as-seen-in-apples-telephone-app), thats allows you to stick in a delegate. it should be fairly easy to use it for an ATM Interface.

Answer (score 0):

To format the string you can use NSNumberFormatter. Something like this:

```
float input = 20049.0f / 100.0;

NSNumberFormatter* formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];    
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

NSNumber *nsInput = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:input];
NSString* formattedOutput = [formatter stringFromNumber:nsInput];
NSLog(@"Output as currency: %@", formattedOutput);

[formatter release];
```

Comment: I've played a bit with NSNumberFormatter for currency, but I've had some problems where if I try to use numberFromString to parse the string back into a float after editing, it'll always return zero (apparently because the currency symbol is missing?). Is that the best way to translate the string value back into a number?

Comment: Hm. Have you tried [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle] when converting from string to a number?

Answer (score 0):

<del>I have implemented [SATextField](https://github.com/Stunner/SATextField) that has this functionality built-in. It works just like a UITextField and has the same appearance. Merely set the `fixedDecimalPoint` property to `YES`.</del>

**EDIT:** I have created a new project that contains this functionality: [STAControls](https://github.com/Stunner/STAControls) (specifically, use [`STAATMTextField`](https://github.com/Stunner/STAControls/blob/master/STAControls/STAControls/TextField/STAATMTextField.h) -- *it even supports `.` entry!*). The difference is that this project has been implemented as a legitimate subclass of `UITextField` whereas `SATextField` was merely a container class housing a `UITextField` instance.