# Building an something that's iPhone Phone like

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I was looking to find an answer to this but could not (maybe because every time I search for Phone I get iPhone related stuff..). I am basically looking to replicate the iPhone Phone app so trying to figure out the following:

1. how can I create the Phone keypad UI (the numbers, Call button, etc.)? Is there an API for that or is it custom?
2. Can I access the actual phone from my app, meaning, could I dial from my app?

Comment: Not sure about your specific queries, but keep in mind that Apple rarely approve apps that replace or duplicate core iPhone functions. So even if you write the best dialling app in the world, the best you could hope for is to be 1) sued, 2) bought, 3) integrated into iOS 6 and 4) be called magical and credited to Steve Jobs

Comment: it's slightly more than that, not really a direct dialing like the phone app. it's very different, but the need is the same - same UI (or similar) and the ability to dial from the app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to create a numeric pad as seen in Apples telephone app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391464/best-way-to-create-a-numeric-pad-as-seen-in-apples-telephone-app)

Comment: not really Brad, I am looking to build the Phone app native UI. This one is a keypad while you are on a call, not a dialer. thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is akosmas' code on github: https://github.com/akosma/iphone-keypad/

   *This project features a keypad taken bit by bit from the one supplied in the iPhone. Pure copyright infringement? Not really, simply another form of flattery.* (quot. the author)
2. As seen here: [Dial number in iOS really need confirmation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933709/dial-number-in-ios-really-need-confirmation)

   ```
   NSURL *url = [ [ NSURL alloc ] initWithString: @"tel:212-555-1234" ];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
   ```

Alex is right: make sure to change the set colors a little bit before submitting.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think it is custom.
2. No, you can't. You can launch the phone app with a link in a web view.

Answer (score 0):

1. Custom
2. No, unless you invoke the phone app, or jailbreak.